Need help on tricky/nasty limit involving incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind
I have the following limit I need to take involving the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^{+}} F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)
$$
where I'm using the Wolfram/Mathematica syntax for the elliptic integral of the first kind, this limit seems to stump Mathematica and it cannot find an expression for it. However, if I take the limit bit by bit, I can get the following
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to0^{+}} &F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) =\\
& F\left(\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)
\end{align*}
where
$$
\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right) = -i\cdot \infty = \lim_{t'\to-\infty} i\cdot t'
$$
So I can make the following substitution and I find the limit using Mathematica (v14.1)
\begin{align*}
F&\left(\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) =\\
&F\left(\lim_{t'\to-\infty} i\cdot t,\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) = i K\left(1 -\frac{2. \sqrt{1 -4. z}}{-2 z+\sqrt{1 -4. z}+1}\right) 
\end{align*}
I question this answer because what I can also do is the following:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to0^{+}} &F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) =\\
& F\left(\arcsin\left(\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)
\end{align*}
where I've put the limit inside the radical argument of arcsine. I can write that
\begin{align*}
\text{if }z>\frac{1}{4}&\implies\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right) \infty = \lim_{t'\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right) t'\\
\text{if }0<z<\frac{1}{4}&\implies\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}} = -i \cdot \infty = -\lim_{t'\to\infty} i \cdot  t'\\
\text{if }z<0&\implies\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}} = \infty = \lim_{t'\to\infty} t'\\
\end{align*}
Leading to the expressions
\begin{gather*}
\hspace{-1.5in}F\left(\arcsin\left(\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) =\\
\hspace{1.5in}\begin{cases}
F\left(\arcsin\left( \lim\limits_{t'\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right) t' \right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) & \text{if } z>\frac{1}{4}\\
F\left(\arcsin\left( -\lim\limits_{t'\to\infty} i t' \right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)=\\
\phantom{AAA} \phantom{-}F\left(-\arcsin\left( \lim\limits_{t'\to\infty} i t' \right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)= & \text{if } 0<z<\frac{1}{4}\\
\phantom{AAA} -F\left(\arcsin\left( \lim\limits_{t'\to\infty} i t' \right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) \\
F\left(\arcsin\left( \lim\limits_{t'\to\infty} t' \right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) & \text{if } z<0
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
This simplifies to
\begin{equation*}
F\left(\arcsin\left(\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right) =
\begin{cases}
iK\left(1 -\frac{2 \sqrt{1 -4 z}}{-2 z+\sqrt{1 -4 z}+1}\right) & \text{if } z>\frac{1}{4}\\
-iK\left(1 -\frac{2 \sqrt{1 -4 z}}{-2 z+\sqrt{1 -4 z}+1}\right)
& \text{if } 0<z<\frac{1}{4}\\
\left(1- \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1 -4 z}}{\sqrt{1 -4 z}-2 z+1}} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1 -4 z}-2 z+1}{\sqrt{1 -4 z}}}\right) K\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{1 -4 z}}{-2 z+\sqrt{1 -4 z}+1}\right)+-i K\left(1 -\frac{2 \sqrt{1 -4 z}}{-2 z+\sqrt{1 -4 z}+1}\right) & \text{if } z<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
These different results are a bit conflicting and I would like to know if Mathematica is coming to the correct answers. I do not know much about elliptic integral properties to really glean much from how these answers were arrived at. If I wanted to actually derive the results myself, how would I go about doing that?\
EDIT: The limit here comes from the solution to a weighted line integral
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma w(x,y)ds = &\int_0^\beta w(x(t),y(t)) \sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt \\ =&f(t)\cdot F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z} - t^{-1}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}}\right),\frac{2\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-2z+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)\Bigg|_{0}^\beta
\end{align*}
The function is undefined at $t=0$, hence why the limit is taken as $t$ approaches zero from the right. The weight function, $w(x(t),y(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^+$, for all $t\in(0,\beta)$

As you are already noticing in your investigations, a lot depends on how you treat the arcsin. I suspect that this in turn depends on what you need this limit for. Could you expand a bit on that?

@Hrodelbert It comes from the solution to a weighted line integral. Thank you for pointing out the unclarity of the question. I've added an edit.

thanks for the clarification. It is still not clear what role $z$ plays in your problem. Any chance you can tell us what $w$ is more explicitly?

It is the corresponding output value of a level curve of a particularly odd polynomial surface, where $z\in\mathbb{R}$. The $w$ is the reciprocal of a function that gives the length of that level curve from parameter $t=0$ to $t=\beta$.

For the problem I needed it for, I found an alternative route that allowed me to avoid this limit altogether. That being said, the original question regarding it still stands

For what it's worth, I believe Mathematica outputs consistent values, but it needs to make assumptions about domains in order to compute these limits. It does so by choosing standard conventions, such as that the square root has a branch cut along the negative real line. Given your description it seems too naive to assume that these choices coincide with what you need. The only way to arrive at the result you are aiming for is to be careful about what happens to the level curve as a function of $z$.
